# How to make content touch the edge of a viewport in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble making content touch the edge of the browser with Twitter Bootstrap.

I am developing a website that is full-width and where there are images that touch the edges of viewports. I have used `.container-fluid` div to my `.row` and `col-` divs.

What I have tried so far:

1. I tried removing padding from `.container-fluid`, but unfortunately this makes a horizontal scrollbar to appear in the browser;
2. I attached a custom class that removed padding from individual `col-'s`, but this does not seem right to play with the core Bootstrap grid system to achieve such a simple effect. What is more, the purpose is not to remove all gutters, but in a first and last `col-` in a `row` (left and right gutter, respectively)
3. I introduced negative margins to different elements on my site so that they eat up the padding on both sides of the browser that I want to get rid off - this, however, makes a horizontal scrollbar appear, too.

I have serched the web to find a solution to this problem but, unfortunately, there wasn't a clear answer offered.

To put it concisely:

What do you do to make content touch the edges of a viewport when developing with Bootstrap?

Comment: If you want people to help you show the code that you have been using.

Comment: To put it concisely: you use container-fluid with the proper grid formatting (always nest columns under a row). The horizontal scroll appears because you aren't doing it properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't modify the base css, you create classes and use as needed. I prefer to make an .inner element for my columns if I have gutter in the middle but not on the outer edges. And you do have use overflow-x:hidden.

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/lujedi/1/

*http://jsbin.com/lujedi/1/edit?html,css,output*

[image]

**HTML:**

```
         <div class="container-fluid full-width">
            <div class="row row-no-gutter">
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />    
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />    
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />    
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" /> 
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- close .container-fluid full-width -->
  
  <hr>
  
         <div class="container-fluid full-width has-inner">
            <div class="row row-no-gutter">
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                 <div class="inner">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />
                 </div>
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                 <div class="inner">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />
                 </div>
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                 <div class="inner">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />
                 </div>
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                 <div class="inner">
                     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-full-width" alt="" />
                 </div>
               </div>
               <!-- close .col -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- close .container-fluid full-width -->
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid.full-width {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.row.row-no-gutter {
    margin: 0
}
.row.row-no-gutter [class*="col-"] {
    padding: 0
}
.img-full-width {
    width: 100.5%;
    height: auto;
}
.has-inner .row.row-no-gutter {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
.row.row-no-gutter .inner {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for digging kittens. I have a new kitten, he acts like a puppy too. I lucked out.

Comment: awesome that fix 100.5% to stop 1px gaps in chrome.

Comment: @Christina: I need a similar solution, instead the container is fluid, I need to have it as Fixed. 
My requirement is to have an edge to edge for 1280px container having 50px of gutter within the 12 column grid. I have asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56446193/769456 with Bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. In the meantime I have been testing the code and arrived at this solution - which also does the trick for my:

```
.no-gutter [class*="col-"]:first-child  {
padding-left:0;
}

.no-gutter [class*="col-"]:last-child {
padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when you put a responsive image in there and the rest of the columns in that row, the middle column images will be shorter because there's padding on the left and right but the outer column images will be taller. When you use the answer I created, the images are the same because the padding is the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5 solution (2023)** -

Just in case someone is looking for the solution on Bootstrap 5 you need to drop the outer `container, container-fuild` etc completely for an edge to edge layout.

Read more under the section "No gutters" in the official documentation link -

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/