# Remove gutter from Bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

With Bootstrap 4, I have been asked to customise the default grid system for desktop like this:

[image]

wherein, the container & desktop breakpoint is 1280px.

The example I have tried is :

```css
   

 body {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.l-wrap {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  width: calc((100% - 50px * 11) / 12);
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
}

/* For a 3-column grid */
.grid-item:nth-child(1n+12) {
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

/* Demo purposes */
.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="l-wrap">
  <div class="col-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Grid item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine. But I am trying to achieve same in Bootstrap.

The `gutter width is 50px` but it lies within `container`.

> This should give me a `column width = 61px` as my gutter is going to be `50*11 = 550`. So 1280-550/12 = 60.83.

By default, bootstrap leaves the gutter from either side.

> Solutions that I've tried

1. I tried padding left & padding right from 1st & last column respectively, leaving the grid column to be of different width ( *Problem*)
2. Tried utilizing `SCSS` mixin to generate column

```
@include media-breakpoint-up('lg', $breakpoints) {
   @for $i from 1 through $columns {
      .col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
         padding-right: 0;
         padding-left: 0;
         @include make-col($i, $columns);
      }
   }
}
```

So that, I can remove the padding from either side and then have a custom CSS on top of it to achieve this behaviour but no *success*

Appreciate if anyone can guide on how to achieve this in Bootstrap, please?

Comment: I am not clear about what you want to do. You mentioned break point 1280px but from your graph it seems like you want the container's width to be 1280px? The break point and the container max width are 2 different things. Please be specific. Also do you mean to override gutter width only at and above 1280px break point? Or you want the gutter width that way from the beginning?

Comment: Yes, @DavidLiang. You're right. My breakpoint is 1280px and container width is also the same. I've set the same using `$container-max-widths`. 

Basically, I don't need outer gutter for 1280px container. The gutter needs to be within the `container`
`Susy` framework does provide it .e.g. https://www.oddbird.net/2017/06/13/susy-spread/
(Check container-spread:narrow )

Comment: I am not familiar with Susy framework. I was going to say if you override the bootstrap variable `$grid-gutter-width`, you're basically done. Bootstrap rows have negative margins to accommodate the outer gutters.

Comment: @DavidLiang: I am a bit new to TB. Not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: You can read the theming section here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/, specially variable defaults section. I could've provided an answer for your OP but I am not so clear about what you want to achieve and the framework you're using so I didn't.

Comment: @DavidLiang
I don't have a choice to change a framework now. so will have to stick with TB.
TB adds gutter from either side so for.e.g if I set it to 50px then it will have 25px from both sides. isn't it?

Do you mean, I shall then control row margins by placing negative margins? Will it result in all columns to be of equal width then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The narrow effects for container and gutter from Susy can be achieved easily in Bootstrap using three key changes:

1. Omit using `container` or `container-fluid` class, [as stated in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters).

   Edit: If you need to restrict the container to 1280px, check the edit below.
2. Set default padding of columns to 25px on each side (so 50px total), instead of the initial 30px total
3. Adjust the negative margin on the row to reflect the gutter change by modifying the default to `-25px` margin on each side

So essentially your CSS would be:

```
.row {
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.col,
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

One advantage of this approach is its responsiveness – it is not locked to any screen size such as 1280px. This can be seen in action in this [jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/syrv7mab/) or below. Have added some responsive width output for debugging and testing in the former, omitted in the snippet below for brevity.

Edit: If you need to have the container size restricted to 1280px, you could do:

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1280px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

The above will ensure that the container stays at maximum 1280px when the screen is 1280px in width or more, or stick to the default Bootstrap responsiveness when it is less. If you do prefer to have it always at 1280px, remove the media breakpoint and set both width and max-width to 1280px.

```css
#example-row {
  background: #0074D9;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.example-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFDC00;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}

.col,
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" id="example-container">
  <div class="row" id="example-row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="example-content">Grid Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All of this can also be done in the source code with SASS – [check the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers) for the mixins.

Lastly, if you do need to have these changes to default sizes only for some special content, change the classes above to a new name (e.g. `.container-1280`) and amend the HTML accordingly.

Comment: Really appreciate the solution. But I do need to restrict the container to 1280px, as the content is going to fall within this container.

Comment: @Robin in that case you would only have to amend the Bootstrap `container` class as well. Check the edit for instructions in that regard.

Comment: @Robin Could you ensure that you are loading the bootstrap stylesheet before your custom CSS one? Otherwise the defaults will take priority